# make a new array from a nested object using Lodash

Tags: lodash

Here is my data

```
[
    {
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "data": "companya data",
                "company": "Company A"
            }
        },
        "uniqueId" : 1
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "data": "companyb data",
                "company": "Company B"
            }
        },
        "uniqueId" : 2
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "data": "companyc data",
                "company": "Company C"
            }
        },
        "uniqueId" : 3
    }
]
```

The format I need for my typeahead directive is below. I was trying to figure out the other post I made but still couldn't make it work. The best was to just make the nested collection as a simple collection of object.

```
[
    {
        "uniqueId" : 1,
        "data": "companya data"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId" : 2,
        "data": "companyb data"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId" : 3,
        "data": "companyc data"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
console.log(
    _(jsonData).map(function(obj) {
        return {
            d : obj.properties.key.data,
            id : obj.uniqueId
        }
    }) 
    .value()  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the chaining feature of lodash as long as you are only performing one operation. You can simply use:

```
_.map(jsonData, function(obj) {
    return {
        d : obj.properties.key.data,
        id : obj.uniqueId
    }
});
```